How to boot an OS (Ubuntu) installed for a diferent (protected) PC?
Last year I bought a Samsung Galaxy Book 2 (i5 12th gen notebook). It features a different BIOS setup screen and soon I learned I was unable to run OSes installed in different machines there.
I mean, I grabbed my old SATA SSD, containing a previous Ubuntu OS install, but it didn't run. After moving BIOs setup options around a little, I gave up and reinstalled the OS from scratch so it could work in this notebook.
Now the notebook has a battery problem, so I took my SATA SSD out of the Samsung notebook and I'm trying to boot my daily OS in a spare PC. The spare PC is a  X99+Zeon motherboard, driver issues are not my problem yet because I just cannot book this same disk in the desktop PC.
So I would like to know what technical lock/requirement am I facing in here? I's used to swapping disks and OSes across multiple desktops and also few notebooks, but this one is giving me a hard time. Am I able to run my OS tuning the desktop BIOS setup somehow?

If the notebook's disk is not at all accessible on the x99 PC, that might be a SATA disk password lock implemented by the notebook firmware.
Otherwise, if the problem is just in booting, it sounds like a difference between UEFI and classic BIOS. A new notebook might we'll be UEFI-only; a system with a x99 chipset is likely to have an early x64 implementation of UEFI (which might have bugs), and might still be configured to default to classic BIOS-style boot anyway.
In Linux, if the directory /sys/firmware/efi/ exists, then the system has booted in native UEFI mode and you should be able to view boot settings with sudo efibootmgr -v. If the directory does not exist, the system may or may not be UEFI-capable, but is currently booted in legacy BIOS compatibility mode.
If the old SSD also has an UEFI-mode OS installed, you might need to run sudo grub-install --force-extra-removable to make its UEFI bootloader accessible in a standard UEFI removable media/fallback boot path too, to make the disk automatically detect as UEFI-bootable in another system.
